# How is this crystal / ferrite bead / ground shield connected?

Tags: usb, ground, crystal, shielding, ferrite

This is part of the schematic for a [TI TAS1020B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tas1020b.pdf) USB Streaming Controller MCU that I don't quite understand. Obviously the shield connects to one end of the ferrite bead, but what else? Are the XTAL pins connected the shield as well? And, does the shield have to be tied to other ground planes at a single point elsewhere (the way you usually do with isolated grounds) or is the connection through the ferrite bead the single point of connection? Does the shield have to wrap the components and traces exactly as shown?

*From Figure 4-1 on page 71 of the linked datasheet:*

[image: Relevant part of Schematic]

Comment: What chip is it?

Comment: TAS1020b, a USB controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the datasheet:

> ## 2.2.1 Clock Generation
>
> The TAS1020B requires an external 6-MHz crystal with load capacitors
> and PLL loop filter components to derive all the clocks needed for
> both USB and codec operation. Figure 4-1 shows the connection of these
> components to the TAS1020B. **Figure 4-1 also shows a ground shield
> residing on the top layer of the PCB and underneath the crystal and
> its load capacitors and the PLL components. The PLL is an analog PLL,
> and noise pickup in these components can translate to phase jitter at
> the output of the PLL, which in turn can translate to distortion at
> the codec. A ground shield is recommended to attenuate the digital
> noise components on the board as seen at the PLL.**
>
> The AVSS and AVDD pins on the TAS1020B are used exclusively to power
> the analog PLL. To maintain isolation from the digital noise residing
> on a board, AVSS should be a separate ground plane that connects to
> the primary ground plane (DGND) at a single point via a ferrite bead.
> The ferrite bead should exhibit around 9 Ω of impedance at 100 MHz.
> AVDD should also be distinct from DVDD. A recommended architecture is
> to generate DVDD and AVDD from the same regulator line, with each
> derived from a RC filter in series with the regulator output. It is
> finally recommended that the ground shield for the crystal and its
> load capacitors and the PLL loop filter components be connected to
> AVSS at a single point via a ferrite bead of the same type as above.
>
> Using the low frequency 6-MHz crystal and generating the required
> higher frequency clocks internally in the TAS1020B is a major
> advantage with regard to EMI.

*(emphasis mine)*

So it's basically suggesting that you should put a copper filled polygon on the top layer underneath the crystal and it's load capacitors and connect it to your analog ground via a ferrite bead in order to provide a low impedance current return path to reduce jitter on the PLL.

Comment: Thanks very much. That will teach me to read the fine print!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the shaded area is understood to be connected to the main ground.  The ferrite bead is decoupling the high frequency signals between the analog ground and the main ground while still providing a good DC connection.

This is just a guess from only the small layout snippet you show.